# How to define max uploaded file size & allowed file types in NodeJs restify bodyParser?

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm a newbie in node.js. I have already done to upload image file to Rest server using Restify module. but now, I need to insure that my uploaded image file size & allowed file types in bodyParser restify.

my restify code is:

```
var restify = require('restify'),
    fsEx = require('fs-extra'),
    md5 = require("md5"),
    path = require("path");

var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'Photo Upload api server'
});

server.use(restify.bodyParser({
    maxBodySize: 2,
    mapParms: true,
    mapFiles: true,
    keepExtensions: true
}));


server.post('/resized', function(req, res, next) {

    var tempPath = req.files.photos.path;
    var getFileExt = path.extname(tempPath);
    var finalFileName = Date.now() + getFileExt;
    var finalImgPath = __dirname + "/uploads/" + finalFileName;

    fsEx.move(tempPath, finalImgPath, function(err) {

        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }


    });

    console.log('result FinalImage = ', finalImgPath);

    res.end('image resized');
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const maximumImageSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
const allowedImageFormats = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'];

const isValidImageFormat = (extension) => _.includes(allowedImageFormats, _.toLower(extension));
const isValidImageSize = (size) => size < maximumImageSize;

const imageExtension = path.extname(file.name);
if (!isValidImageFormat(imageExtension)) {
    return next(new restify.errors.ForbiddenError('Invalid image format.'));
}

const imageSize = Number(req.headers['content-length']);
if (!isValidImageSize(imageSize)) {
    return next(new restify.errors.ForbiddenError('Image is too big.'));
}
```

Comment: nice idea, but the `content-length` is not the image size, it is body size.

Comment: True. This code is from a project where the endpoint only uploaded a single image so in this case it works. But you're correct, if the body contains more than an image something else needs to be done.